# Conditionally changing a SplashScreen image during runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, splash-screen

I have an existing image showing as a splash screen when my application is loading.  I followed:

[How to: Add a Splash Screen to a WPF Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-wpf-application?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

I set an image's Build Action to 'SplashScreen' (I'll call this the "built-in" way of doing a splash screen).  Everything is working well and my image is showing during application load.

Now, I'd like to dynamically change between two different static images - depending on whether a condition (decided at runtime) has been met.

I've tried adding a *second* image and setting its Build Action to 'SpashScreen', but this creates several build errors (none of them seem to directly relate to the image property change).  I could also create a custom Window and display it manually, but this seems to cause a delay that the built-in splash screen doesn't have. The built-in functionality also works well on all resolutions.

Is there a way to change between different splash screen images, depending on a condition?

Comment: Look at the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.splashscreen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSBuild action is a simplified way of setting a splash screen.

- [How to: Add a Splash Screen to a WPF Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-wpf-application?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

However, you can also create it manually through code to have more control over when it is shown and when it is closed. You can simply create an instance of the [`SplashScreen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.splashscreen?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) type and pass the path to an image in your project or elsewhere.

In this example, I added images and set their `BuildAction` to `Resource`. Then I overrode the [`OnStartup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.onstartup?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) method (you could alternatively add an event handler to the [`Startup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.startup?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Application.Startup)%3Bk(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event) and selected the path of the splash screen image depending on a few conditions and finally created an instance of [`SplashScreen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.splashscreen?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and show it using the [`Show(bool autoClose)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.splashscreen.show?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-splashscreen-show(system-boolean)) method. The `autoClose` flag is set to `true`, so the splash screen is closed as soon as the application is started. If you want to decide yourself when to close it, pass `false` and call the [`Close`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.splashscreen.close?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) method instead. There is also an overload of [`Show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.splashscreen.show?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-splashscreen-show(system-boolean-system-boolean)) to make the splash screen the topmost window.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
   protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
   {
      string splashScreenPath;
      if (isPiratedVersionOfMyApp)
         splashScreenPath = @"\Resources\PiratedSplashScreen.jpg";
      else if (isMagicVersionOfMyApp)
         splashScreenPath = @"\Resources\MagicSplashScreen.jpg";
      else
         splashScreenPath = @"\Resources\DefaultSplashScreen.jpg";

      SplashScreen splashScreen = new SplashScreen(splashScreenPath);
      splashScreen.Show(true);

      base.OnStartup(e);
      // ...other code.
   }
}
```